# Django - multi-level table challenge

Tags: django, navigation, report, traversal

I'm new to Django, but an older programmer ;o)

I've managed to create a functionally working site that has 5 tables. Where each one is a 1-to-M relationship to the one below it.
Also created the breadcrumb at the top of each page.
I'm using htmx to allow interaction with the 0 to many records under the parent record directly above.

Two challenges, how to traverse all 5 tables to

1. Display all data for a given A record and/or create a report for a given A record and
2. Create a navigation sidebar or similar for the first 3 levels to provide visibility of what entries you've got

Example of potential structure

```
-> A
  -> B
    -> C
      -> D
        -> E
      -> D
        -> E
  -> B
    -> C
      -> D
        -> E
        -> E
      -> D
        -> E
```

looking for some thoughts or any pointers to examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of solved my own question.
I created database views with unmanaged models in Django.
These views are used for various "reports" across the hierarchy.
One report is called all_items and when displaying via django template have the values as clickable links to goto the appropriate list/edit pages.
This way achieve the aim of providing full visibility of data entered.

See my other question for the creation of the views

Comment: You can use `django-mptt` you will have all the methods to manipulate children objects and children of children when some parents are deleted and so on. If you want some example let me know.